# Specific column alignment in typesetting a resume

Tags: resume

I am in the process of transferring my resume from a word processor format to LaTeX. For the body of the resume, I'd like each section (e.g. education, work experience) to appear like

[image]

I used a table in Word with two columns to get that look but I can't implement this in `LaTeX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the `currvita` package. Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currvita}
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{Curriculum Vit\ae}
\begin{cvlist}{}
\item[Education]
Massachusetts\\
\textit{Candidate for Bachelor of Science in}\\
\dots
\end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, just two questions: how do you adjust the distance between columns, and how do you remove the date at the bottom of the generated pdf?

Comment: @djlovesupr3me Check out the [documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/currvita/currvita.pdf). Specifically, the NoDate option to `currvita` and `\cvlabelwidth` for the width of the label.